# Error: Model in Pspice is undefined

Tags: oscillator, spice, model

When I simulate the circuit below in Pspice, the output info says: `model J2n5485 used by Q2N5485 is undefined`. But I have defined the model in the code.

I need to use the 2N5485 FET in this circuit in Pspice:

My version: 9.1 student.

[image: Schematic of simulated circuit]

My .cir:

```
oscilador de cristal pierce jfet

Vcc 4 0 5
.lib nom.lib
L1 4 1 3mH
C1 1 2 0.001UF
R1 3 0 10M
*|||CRISTAL|||
Rs 6 3 15
Cs 5 6 25e-005
Cp 2 3 6e-012
LS 2 5 10.132118mH

Q2N5485 1 3 0 J2n5485
.lib eval.lib
.MODEL J2n5485 njf
+VTO=-2.3888 BETA=0.00110073 LAMBDA=0.0108464 RD=3.58556 
+RS=3.44889 IS=1.44179E-14 CGS=430.467E-15 CGD=433.667E-15 
+PB=1.160107 FC=0.5 KF=8E-18 AF=1
+VTOTC=0.002 XTI=3 BETATCE=-0.5

.AC DEC 10 10 5MEG
.PROBE
.END
```

Answer (score 4):

At least in Orcad PSPICE you have to point the simulator to the custom library file, using something like this:

PSPICE->Edit Simulation Profile->Configuration Files

Then browse to the model filename and add it as a Design or Global Configured File.

If you don't do that, you'll get exactly the symptom you describe.

Answer (score 0):

*Spehro Pefhany* is right that you should place the model into a file (a library file or a file that will be included).

In fact, it is also possible to use "*your*" way (Millares'), but it is quite complicated since the schematic editor normally **overwrites** the netlist (so the .MODEL item inserted in it manually will be lost then). I myself use the editor *Schematics* (Microsim's) instead of the *OrCAD Capture* editor to capture schematics.

If *any change* is made in the circuit within the *Schematics* editor, then the subsequent  simulation run leads to the same error message (*undefined model*; because of the netlist having been freshly overwritten -> the model placed there deleted), but if *after that* the .MODEL item is manually inserted into the netlist *again*, saved and the simulation run then, it works well (no change may be made within *Schematics* editor). I admit the described procedure isn't very comfortable. I haven't checked the behaviour of the *OrCAD Capture* editor in an analogical case.

Further, I have a few, in my opinion quite important, notes concerning the circuit simulation:

1. In *Spice simulators* both suffixes '**M**' and '**m**' mean the same - i.e. **milli** (the netlist is case insensitive), so the value of **R1 is 10 m\$ \Omega \$** instead of the intended 10 M\$ \Omega \$! The 'Mega' prefix of a physical unit is determined by **MEG** suffix in the Spice value syntax (or **meg, Meg**, etc.).
2. To initiate the crystal (high Q) oscillations, it is helpful, according to my experience, to '*inject* some small current' by setting up the 'crystal inductor' non-zero initial condition (IC=100pA in my example, see below; else start of oscillations takes a long time, if it ever starts).
3. I don't get (the purpose of) the *.AC DEC 10 10 5MEG* statement (AC Sweep) in the original netlist, since there is no AC source within the circuit. IMHO the transient analysis should be carried out. I have set up the following statement: *.TRAN 0.1ns 100us 0 25ns* for my transient analysis, its result is presented below.
4. The circuit, as defined in the original netlist, will cause the simulator complaint, reading something like '***nodes 2 and 5 are floating***', since these nodes have **no DC path to ground** due to C1 and Cs. No analysis can be done in such a case.
5. Even if a path to ground is *somehow* arranged (in the original circuit), the oscillator doesn't oscillate (improper feedback phase at the oscillation frequency). The following, slightly modified circuit works:

[image]

Its netlist is as follows:

```
* Pierce Crystal Oscillator with N-JFET *

V_Vcc     4 0  5V
L_L1      4 2  3mH
C_C1      2 0  0.001uF
R_R1      3 0  10Meg

* CRYSTAL
R_Rs      6 3  15
C_Cs      5 6  250uF
C_Cp      2 3  6pF
L_Ls      2 5  10.13211mH IC=100pA

J_Q2N5485 2 3 0 J2n5485_local_model

.MODEL J2n5485_local_model njf
+ VTO=-2.3888 BETA=0.00110073 LAMBDA=0.0108464 RD=3.58556
+ RS=3.44889 IS=1.44179E-14 CGS=430.467E-15 CGD=433.667E-15
+ PB=1.160107 FC=0.5 KF=8E-18 AF=1
+ VTOTC=0.002 XTI=3 BETATCE=-0.5
```

and the corresponding V(2) waveform looks like this:

[image]